# Cnn prediction is very poor inspite of 70% of accuracy

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning

I am new to stackoverflow and deep learning.I have been following a example of multi label image classification from below.

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/04/build-first-multi-label-image-classification-model-python/

I reduced the images to 500...with 2 epochs...It gives accuracy of around 72% in test set and training test.This I did because I was getting memory error.

But the predictions are very very poor...I took a image from training set..Even for that the prediction is completely wrong...

Please can you help me out.Apologies in case I missed something from my end.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jankey, 2 epochs is not enough to properly train a neural network, you can start with 50 for MNIST. If you have memory issues, try to decrease batch size to 8 or 16.

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), batch_size=16)
```

You can also decrease the number of `convolution filters` to 32 and number of nodes in `Dense` layer to 32. Try to make it more efficient according to your infrastructure limitations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick help.I will try these suggestions.Thanks a lot once again from my end.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestion and guidance .I did the following changes.

1) model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), batch_size=32)

2) kept two convolutional layers with 32 filters

3) Change input shape as (64,64,3) tested then changed to (224,224,3).

With these I am able to get better predictions.Not 100%.But far better.
Will try to tune and test the model further.

Again Thanks for quick help.